# Express-validator validation causes typescript error: request.query Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, express, express-validator

I am building a Node.js app using express, which I wanted to improve with express-validator. This is my first time with express-validator and I don't understand the warnings it causes. Its documentation is also not really verbose.

Here is a simplified version of a segment before I added the validation, the database calls have been replaced by sending a response back with the `entry_id` from the GET request.

```
router.get(
  '/list_entries',
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.query.entry_id)
  }
)
```

I added validation to check if `entry_id` is given in `req.query` and is in the valid range.:

```
router.get(
  '/list_entries',
  query('entry_id').isInt({ min: 1 }),
  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
    res.send(req.query.entry_id)
  }
)
```

It seems to function well, in case of out of range values the errors do get displayed.
However, this also triggered a warning in typescript stating:`Object is possibly 'undefined'` referring to `req.query` in the response. I don't have a clear understanding how does the validation cause this, and how can I overcome it (other than using optional chaining like `req.query?.entry_id`). I wonder where I can find some documentation or working examples to enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might have something to do with your `tsconfig.json` file and not the express-validator. It may be raised by this setting ` "strictNullChecks": true` on your config. If you set it to false, then you should be good... It's basically telling you that you should check `req.query` is not null/undefined before trying to use it (req.query.entry_id)

Comment: Thanks, strictNullChecks is indeed true in my `tsconfig.json`. I fail to see why the TS error does not appear though (on line number 4 in the first example) when I'm not using express-validator. My only guess is that express-validator does modify `req` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has little to do with Express Validator and is just Typescript being careful.

It has reasoned that it cannot *prove* (at compile-time) that `req.query` is defined, so it is warning you `req.query.entry_id` might cause a TypeError at run-time.

The simplest solution is to write this:

```
res.send(req.query?.entry_id)
```

which is simply shorthand for:

```
res.send(req.query === undefined ? undefined : req.query.entry_id)
```

Comment: Maybe it has little to do with express validator, but still, if I don't use express validator (as in my first example), I do not get the same TypeError. So on first glimpse express validator does trigger it - I'd like to understand where this difference comes from.

Comment: No, it is not some particular feature of the validator that is doing it.  For some reason, `req.query` is declared as possibly-undefined, and the rest is inevitable.

Comment: @Malvolio You're spreading misinformation. It IS a particular feature of the validator, it explicitly overrides the `express` type definitions to declare `query` as optional

Answer (score 1):

Like TypeScript mentions, `req.query` is possibly `undefined`. It's the case when there are no query string in the url for example. So to be sure that it is not `undefined` you will have to add an additional check. Also don't forget to check the presence of `req.query.entry_id`:

```js
function expressCallback (req, res) {
  if (req.query) {
    if (req.query.entry_id) res.send(req.query.entry_id)
  }
}
```

If you are not a huge fan of wrapping all your logic in an `if` block, you can give a default value to `req.query` to be an empty object:

```js
function expressCallback (req, res) {
  const query = req.query || {}

  if (query.entry_id) res.send(query.entry_id)
}
```

Have a look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4AcBOyDOODCAhgDbEBGhEA1ogBQBQii2AjgFyIDeiLIymAT0QB+Dt2RgoggPowAJqMQ4pMMAHNEAXy0AaRI2a4xSiXI610hTIQC2HZZlVqAlIgC8APkQA3OPK0GrpwGMMB0rAB0vPwCQQZMoeHILFF8ghESUgKycq7YOBE4prSR0emZMvLOBpr0tfSgkLAIKBj5BCTklFQATHQGrMZlQorikpUK9irqWrr6TPnGRWBmdJbWdkrTLu5evv61THFMEAjKPGlCboYpw4gAPvcABZz1CWG0wxnj2VWGBcs5J9Lt8sjlqpogA).

Comment: Thanks, that's clear, what I don't get is why this problem is triggered only if I add the express-validator call. In the first example I gave, the TS error does not appear, even though I'm using `req.query.entry_id` the same way.